# What to use for sending the User Id, Storage or Send User ID using the Routing In Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working in my Ionic 4 Project and I am confused for sending the User ID, the logic is that: when the user will login and after login it will get the User ID and  after getting the User ID, it will redirect to the particular route. I am confused that it will be better to store the User ID in the storage or send it using the routing.

This is my **userlogin.page.ts:**

```
async UserLoginDetails($soctype, $socid) {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Please Wait',
      duration: 1100,
      translucent: true,
    });
    await loading.present();
    const userdetailslogin = {
      email: this.userlogindet.value.email,
      password: this.userlogindet.value.password,
      social_type: $soctype,
      social_id: $socid,
    };
    this.chakapi.loginUser(userdetailslogin, 'userLogin').subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data) {
        this.responseEdit = data;
        if (this.responseEdit.status === 'success') {
          console.log(this.responseEdit.data.id);
          this.storage.set('ID', this.responseEdit.data.id);
          this.presentAlertConfirm('Login Successful', 1);
        } else {
          this.presentAlertConfirm('Either You are not registered Or not approved user.', 0);
        }
      }
    });
    return await loading.onDidDismiss();
}

async presentAlertConfirm($messge, $para) {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      message: $messge,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'secondary',
          handler: () => {
            // console.log('Confirm Cancel: blah');
            if ($para === 1) {
              this.modalController.dismiss();
              this.router.navigate(['/tabs/tab2']);
            }
          }
        }]
    });
    await alert.present();
}
```

After the successful login, I am storing the User ID in the storage and navigate it to the `this.router.navigate(['/tabs/tab2']);`. This all is working fine but I want to know that it is better way in Ionic 4 and I want to use the User ID multiple times also.

I want to know that it is a good way or not.

Also I want to block this URL `this.router.navigate(['/tabs/tab2']);` when the user is not login and redirect it to some other page.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a guard service to validate user/token.

And to make your routes dynamic you need to do this

```
export const TabsRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'tabs/:id',
    component: TabsComponent,
  },
]
```

Then when you're on your dynamic route component, subscribe to route params, grab the param (in this case it's an object key 'id'), and make your request.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the component is same and I just want to get the User ID.

Comment: And can you please help me how to redirect the user when the user is not login and redirect it to the particular page.

Comment: You can also use the same component for that dynamic route. For validating the user, create a guard service that returns a promise. Set the resolve to true if user has a token, if not then navigate away. Apply the guard service to the routes you want to guard.

Comment: Can you please help me with the more detailed code?